# Bootstrap dropdown's menus are opening outside of the screen after expand

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown in Navbar at right side, when I click on it, its menus are opening far right even not visible until I scroll horizontally.

This is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 0px;" class="navbar-header justify-content-start">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img width="100" src="assets/Acc_logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" 
         aria-haspopup="true" id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="divIcom"></div>
          <div class="divIcom"></div>
          <div class="divIcom"></div>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</nav>
```

also some css added

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

.divIcom {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;
}
```

Styles I am using in `angular.json`

```
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
      "./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
      ]
  },
```

[image]

**Edit 1** -

```
zone.js:1711 Uncaught TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function
    at Mt._createPopper (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:23961)
    at Mt.show (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:22277)
    at Mt.toggle (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:22073)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:26705)
    at HTMLDocument.s (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:4456)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487:34)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:18)
    at globalCallback (zone.js:1704:33)
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: what's the version of bootstrap

Comment: @traynor - It's `bootstrap": "5.2`

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` to trigger dropdown.. this seems like older version using jquery.. it should look fine in 4.x version..

Comment: @traynor - If I am using data-bs-toggle, its not fixing the issue and then dropdown not closing when i click twice on it.

Comment: did you try adding [`dropdown-menu-end`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)? well, it's hard to say.. and mixing incompatible versions is likely to produce even more such cases.. you should pick one and stick with it, and you'll need to include something reproducible, otherwise it's impossible to say..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [`dropdown-menu-sm-end`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment) seems to work fine for `5.2`:

```css
li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .divIcom {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .divIcom {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        display: none;
    }</style>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 0px;" class="navbar-header justify-content-start">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img width="100" src="assets/Acc_logo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="divIcom"></div>
                    <div class="divIcom"></div>
                    <div class="divIcom"></div>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**edit**

try removing extra code, it's probably causing conflicts, leave only bundle (maybe remove jquery also if you're not using it elsewhere), try this::

```
   "scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
      "./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
      ]
```

Comment: Same issue, it opens but its not closing when I click dropdown icon. I copy pasted your code. What could be the issue. I updated my question with one of error in console. Please check. That exception comes when I click dropdown for the first time.

Comment: @R15 try the updated code, remove popper etc., it's already within `bundle`, so another one is probably causing conflict somewhere when clicked, and it breaks everything, which is why it probably stops working..

Answer (score 0):

change this `dropdown-menu-sm-right`

to  `dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-sm-left`

Comment: It's not working I tried.